# Inconsistent memory usage results

Tags: linux, mongodb, memory-management

I have a Linux server running MongoDB on it as you can see in the picture below.
MongoDB service is using %65 of memory but the whole system memory usage is about 4375MB/16047MB. The whole system memory usage and MongoDB memory usage seems conflicting or I'm not interpreting the results correctly.
Can you help please?

[image: htop screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the memory from the 3 running tasks adds up to be ~88%, what your seeing is probably a percentage of the memory that's currently in use. The missing ~12% can probably be found with the other tasks.